# GoTo Next Iteration in For Loop in java

Tags: java, for-loop

Is there a token in java that skips the rest of the for loop?
Something like [VB's Continue](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/801hyx6f.aspx) in java.

Answer (score 433, accepted):

```
continue;
```

`continue;` key word would start the next iteration upon invocation

**For Example**

```
for(int i= 0 ; i < 5; i++){
 if(i==2){
  continue;
 }
System.out.print(i);
}
```

This will print

```
0134
```

---

**See**

- [Document](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/branch.html)

Comment: and `break` will skip the loop :)

Comment: Rather 'break' keyword would terminate the loop.

Answer (score 78):

Try this,

1. If you want to skip a particular iteration, use `continue`.
2. If you want to break out of the immediate loop, use `break`
3. If there are 2 loop, outer and inner.... and you want to break out of both the loop from the inner loop, use break with [label](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/branch.html) ([another question about label](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14960419/is-using-a-labeled-break-a-good-practice-in-java)).

---

Example:

**continue**

```
for(int i=0 ; i<5 ; i++){

    if (i==2){
   
      continue;
    }
 }
```

**break**

```
for(int i=0 ; i<5 ; i++){
    
        if (i==2){
       
          break;
        }
     }
```

**break with label**

```
lab1: for(int j=0 ; j<5 ; j++){
     for(int i=0 ; i<5 ; i++){
    
        if (i==2){
       
          break lab1;
        }
     }
  }
```

Comment: There is also continue with label.

Answer (score 48):

**If you want to skip current iteration, use `continue;`.**

```
for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++){
    if (i == 2){
        continue;
    }
 }
```

**Need to break out of the whole loop? Use `break;`**

```
for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++){
    if (i == 2){
        break;
    }
}
```

**If you need to break out of more than one loop use `break someLabel;`**

```
outerLoop:                                           // Label the loop
for(int j = 0; j < 5; j++){
     for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++){
        if (i==2){
          break outerLoop;
        }
     }
  }
```

*Note that in this case you are not marking a point in code to jump to, you are labeling the loop! So after the break the code will continue right after the loop!

**When you need to skip one iteration in nested loops use `continue someLabel;`, but you can also combine them all.**

```
outerLoop:
for(int j = 0; j < 10; j++){
     innerLoop:
     for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
        if (i + j == 2){
          continue innerLoop;
        }
        if (i + j == 4){
          continue outerLoop;
        }
        if (i + j == 6){
          break innerLoop;
        }
        if (i + j == 8){
          break outerLoop;
        }
     }
  }
```

Answer (score 12):

As mentioned in all other answers, the keyword `continue` will skip to the end of the current iteration.

Additionally you can label your loop starts and then use `continue [labelname];` or `break [labelname];` to control what's going on in nested loops:

```
loop1: for (int i = 1; i < 10; i++) {
    loop2: for (int j = 1; j < 10; j++) {
        if (i + j == 10)
            continue loop1;

        System.out.print(j);
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Use the `continue` keyword. Read [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/branch.html).

> The continue statement skips the current iteration of a for, while , or do-while loop.

Answer (score 2):

use [continue](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/branch.html) keyword .

**EX:**

```
for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
  if(i == 5){
    continue;
   }
}
```